# How to delete Facebook apps from developer console?

Tags: facebook

Maybe I'm missing something here, but I don't see any way to delete apps?

[image]

Comment: Settings > Advanced > Press the big red button down the bottom-left.

Comment: Ok, got it, what a horrible GUI...and then prompts for password EVERY single time also...

Comment: Asking for password confirmation before a majorly destructive action is a good idea. Imagine a multi-million user Facebook app being deleted because you left your computer logged in to Facebook.